# translating VS c code feature to standard gcc: (const char*) lvalue issue

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc

This expression is accepted by the visual studio compiler:

```
((char *) listings) += sometype;
```

but it causes an error under gcc saying: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.

I am looking for a translation (with explanation) of how this code would look in plain c code without the vs features.

```
void *listings = (void *)calloc(width, sometype);
```

Comment: `listings = (char*)listings + sometype;`

Comment: no need of `(void *)` before `calloc`